# android:noHistory not finishing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I had an activity A that used to:

```
private void launchActivityBAndFinish() {
  Intent activityB = makeActivityBIntent();
  startActivity(activityB);
  finish();
}
```

This wasn't good because ActivityB would take some time to start up (it is also potentially in another process or even other app). So as written it would leave a visual gap between ActivityA immediately going away and ActivityB starting. Desired behavior is to keep showing ActivityA (loading spinner) until ActivityB is actually visible.

So I changed it to add `android:noHistory` to ActivityA manifest and remove `finish()` call. It worked as intended (ActivityB is shown smoothly on top of ActivityA, and the latter is gone from history). EXCEPT it didn't actually work when ActivityB is dismissed quickly enough right after being launched (via [X] on fully-visible ActivityB UI that calls `finish()`).

So my questions are:

1) When does `android:noHistory` precisely trigger finish()? [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) say when ActivityA is no longer visible but it doesn't seem to be the case as per described exception.

2) What is the right way to achieve desired UI behavior I'm describing?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you do before call `setContentView`method in your ActivityB? I think you do something that takes much time before draw the layout.

Comment: ActivityB is in another process & potentially another app, so it takes a while to bring up. It also does disk I/O so it will take a while as well to draw content. Hence I'm looking for ways to wait until it's show and then dismiss ActivityA (ActivityB is outside of my control).

Answer (score 0):

In this case ActivityB was translucent hence android:noHistory wasn't shutting down ActivityA.